# moving glyph icon toggled menu bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a reusable toggle sidebar menu and cannot for the life of me get this glyphicon to be anchored to the left of the menu so it is always visible. Right now it looks like the first image in the [album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xvM8.jpg).

I'm using a template so I'm pretty sure that it's just some little css thing I haven't messed with, but my instructor was unable to fix it as well :O

When the menu is toggled, it looks like the second image. I would obviously like the glyphicon to be visible, showing that it can be toggled out again.

And I have one slightly other bad problem (the third image): 
When the menu is toggled closed, there is a scrollbar across the bottom >.<
Here is a link to my html/js and css on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3c7ns5kn/)

And the JS I use for toggling

```
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: bootstrap.css wasn't being loaded in the jsfiddle for me. Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3c7ns5kn/1/

Comment: #menu-toggle {
  text-align: left;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an update JsFiddle with it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3c7ns5kn/2/)

It was the text-indent property and display block causing the issue.

I have changed your CSS to:

```
.sidebar-nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav li.link a {
    text-indent: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```